# URL rewrite with .htaccess and variable sending

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

In the root directory of my website I have an `index.php` file. I want all requests to be served by this file by rewriting them.

The form of the requests will be `domain.com/sub1/sub2/.../subx/string` and I want them to be served by the url `domain.com/index.php?string` where `string` is the last token of the requested url if it is exploded by `/`.

ex.

```
mydomain.com/products/white-shirt/1-20 => mydomain.com/?1-20
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (?:^|/)([^/]+)/?$ /?$1 [L,QSA]
```